# Height function on the torus and regular values

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have the theorem that if $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{N}$ is smooth, and $y\in{f(\mathcal{M})}\subset\mathcal{N}$ is a regular value, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a proper submanifold of dimension $m-n$ (where $m,n$ are the dimensions of $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ respectively).

An example to demonstrate this is the map $f:T_{a,b}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ from the torus (defined as standard in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $a>b>0$, the circle of radius $b$ the one being rotated etc.) to the real line given by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_3$. This is just the height function. Now, intuitively, I can see why $f^{-1}(t)$ is going to be a submanifold of $T_{a,b}$ for $t\in(-a-b,-a+b)\cup(-a+b,a-b)\cup(a-b,a+b)$, since these preimages are essentially going to be either one circle, or two disjoint circles, 'wrapping' around the torus. At the two end points $(-a,-b)$ and $(a+b)$ the preimage is just a point, and in the intermediate points $(-a+b)$ and $(a-b)$, the preimage will be two circles just touching - so in these cases it is clear the preimages aren't submanifolds.

However, in trying to apply the theorem above, I compute the Jacobian of my function $f$ to be $(0,0, 1)$, which has maximal rank 1 for all $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, i.e. it is surjective independently of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. So isn't this theorem telling me $f^{-1}(t)$ is a submanifold for all $t\in[-a-b,a+b]$, which is clearly wrong from what I've explained above?

Comment: Since the torus is 2-dimensional, it would make sense for the gradient/Jacobian to be a 2-vector, not a 3-vector. You should probably write the height function in local coordinates, so that it is a map from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}$. Then you will probably see the singularity after writing it in coordinates.

Comment: Nick is correct (except for using the word "probably"). Also: your torus is standing on end? Usually the term "height" expresses distance along the axis of rotation, not an axis normal to it, as you are obviously describing here. Constant heights along the axis of symmetry yield a circle at $a$ and $-a$, and two circles in $(-a, a)$, which are always submanifolds.